# How To Remove Last Word With Slash In A Textbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to remove the last word on a `Label` with it's slash without putting it in a `String` or an `Array` because the words are typed, looks something like this `D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4` and if i click a button it should remove the `Folder4` and when i click the button again it should remove the `Folder3` and so on.

```
Dim s As String = Label5.Text
Dim r As String = Replace(s, "\", "")
Label5.Text = r
```

And this only removes the slash, how do i add the texts?
I tried something like this:

```
Replace(s, "\" & Label5.Text.TrimEnd, "")
```

but nothing happens. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string class has a method called LastIndexOf that tells you the index of the last character that you pass as parameter.
Then the Substring method allows you to keep only the part before that index

```
 ' Label.Text = "D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4"
 Dim pos As Integer = Label.Text.LastIndexOf("\")
 if pos <> -1 Then
     Label.Text = Label.Text.Substring(0, pos)
 End If
```

No need to split the input in an array and then rebuild your string.

Another method, very simple, (but that carries also an assumption) is to use the Path class

```
' Label.Text = "D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4"
Label.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(Label.Text)
```

The assumption, of course, is in the fact, that you have a correctly typed folder name (not necessary that the folder exists though)

Comment: Thanks but when i run your first code nothing happens. i changed the `"Folders"` to `Label.Text`

Comment: Of course you need to reassign the result to your label text. _Label.Text = test_

Comment: Oops, i forgot. and this is much clearer to understand. Thanks~!!

Answer (score 1):

Idea is, to find last word by splitting the string with `\` and then finding last element in the splitted array

```
Dim s As String = Label5.Text '"D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4"
Dim r As String = s.Replace("\" & s.Split("\")(s.Split("\").Length-1), String.Empty)
Label5.Text=r 'Console.Write(r)
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain it more about this `s.Split("\")(s.Split("\").Length-1), String.Empty`

Comment: You take text in `s`. Then you first `split` it by `backslash`. You want last element from splitted array so `s.Split("\").Length-1` and then replacing it with `Empty`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim r as String = Replace(s, s.Split("\").Last(), "")
```

***.Last()*** will make sure you get the last word after the "\"

Comment: Thanks for the info. But what it does is, it keeps adding the last word after `"\"`.